# Dynamically created radiobutton groups model binding ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a problem. I would like to add to my model dynamically created radiobutton checked values.

I have already made a javascript function which create a radiobutton group on click of a button. These radiobutton group's names are radioYesNo0 (with yes value) radioYesNo0 (with no value); radioYesNo1 (with yes value) radioYesNo1 (with no value), etc.

What to be the type and name of model property that the binding can be possible?

It is a good approach?

Thanks in advance.

I.

Comment: add your code please?

Comment: $('#CbAs').click(function () {
var radioId = $('[name="SATextbox"]').length;
var radioName = "YesNoRadio" + radioId;
var inputName = "<input name=";

SATextbox's length change dynamically too
var radio = inputName + radioName + ' type="radio">';
var div = $('<div class="search">').appendTo("#search-block");
$(radio).appendTo(div); //yes
$(radio).appendTo(div); //no
});

Comment: and             @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Search", FormMethod.Get))
            {
<div class="search" id="search-block">
</div>
}